# Как сделать, чтобы последнее слово внутри абзаца оборачивалось в span?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать, чтобы последнее слово внутри абзаца оборачивалось в span?

```html
<p>Обернуть в span последнее слово</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let p = document.querySelector("p");

p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replace(/\s(\S+)$/, " <span>$1</span>");
```

```css
span { color: red; }
```

```html
<p>Обернуть в span последнее слово?</p>
```

`\s` — "space": Любой пробельный символ,

`\S` — любой символ кроме пробела,

`$` — условное обозначение конца строки.

`$1` в строке-замене ссылается на совпадение внутри скобок.

Придется усложнить регулярное выражение, если хочется брать именно "слово" по каким-то критериям, а не просто "всё, что не пробел".

[RegExp шпаргалка](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)

Answer (score 4):

```js
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
var text = p.innerHTML;         // Получаем текст, который в тэге
var arr = text.split(' ');      // Делим строку на слова
var word = arr[arr.length - 1]; // Берем последнее слово

p.innerHTML = text.slice(0, text.lastIndexOf(word)) + `<span>${word}</span>`;
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Обернуть в span последнее слово</p>
```